# ASUS Zenbook UX425 made in 2020 numpad on touchpad activation issue

Tags: drivers, touchpad, asus, numpad

Is there any driver written for 2020 ASUS Zenbook UX series, to activate numpad on the touchpad?
It should be illuminated numpad, and should be activated by pressing the icon on the up right corer of the touchpad.

Ubuntu 20.10. works perfectly on the laptop, but this small thing is not solved yet.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can install this driver [here](https://github.com/asus-linux-drivers/asus-touchpad-numpad-driver)
It even works on my UX362FA.

Answer (score 2):

I maintain latest & most featured version of Asus numpad/touchpad driver. Link https://github.com/asus-linux-drivers/asus-touchpad-numpad-driver. If any problems persist, please contact me via github contact e-mail or create issue on github repository. If you use laptop Asus WMI hotkeys (Fn+Fx keys) or Asus accessories like stylus you might be interested in other drivers https://github.com/asus-linux-drivers, install them in the same way as numpad one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution for this yet.

For more details see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1810183

Someone needs to make a Linux driver.